# jsPDF not printing Japanese characters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf

I am trying to print out Japanese characters into a pdf

> こんにちは

But every time I looking into the pdf that gets printed it outputs these characters

> þÿ0S0“0k0a0o

A prevoious question was asked [JsPDF not supporting Japanese language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62772841/jspdf-not-supporting-japanese-language)
I would like other people to look into this issue that we have had.

```
import React from "react";
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import "./styles.css";

const HelloWorldJapanese = 'こんにちは';

export default function App() {

  const downloadPdf = () => {
    const doc = new jsPDF()
    doc.text('Hello world!', 10, 10)
    doc.save('a4.pdf')
  }

  const downloadJapanesePDF = () => {
    const doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text(HelloWorldJapanese, 10, 10)
    doc.save('a4.pdf');
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
     <button onClick={downloadPdf}>Download Pdf</button>
     <br />
     <button onClick={downloadJapanesePDF}>Download Japanese Pdf</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does my answer work?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work Doan

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the font-file manually. For instance, in jsPDF [git](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/examples/js/japanese.js)

```
doc.addFont("test/reference/MouhitsuBold.ttf", "Mouhitsu", "bold");

doc.setFont("Mouhitsu", "bold"); // set font
```

I added code in [glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/rare-potent-feet) for easy demonstrate (preview pdf in glitch only work on show in new window)

Comment: I tried your example on glitch, but the Japanese characters still don't show up in my PDF. Do you know what happens?
Previously I also use notosansjp font file, and it shows some unidentified characters.

Comment: After further investigation, I found that it relates to hiragana and katakana. Your sentence is in hiragana, while my sentence is in katakana. What is the easiest way to debug jspdf with custom font?